# VBA - Run-time error '13' when trying to transpose rows value

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I am trying to compare two columns in different worksheets to check if value in column A exist in column B.

When I am trying to transpose row value and store it into dictionary for comparison, run-time error '13' is triggered.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Compare()

Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range
Dim dict As Object, rw As Range
Dim a As Application, tmp As String
Dim Row1Last As Long
Dim Row2Last As Long

Set a = Application
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set sht1 = Worksheets("list_Facility_BOS")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("List_Facility_PG")


With Sheets("list_Facility_BOS")
Row1Last = .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Sheets("List_Facility_PG")
Row2Last = .Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set rngA = sht1.Range("G2:G" & Row1Last)
Set rngB = sht2.Range("H2:H" & Row2Last)

For Each rw In rngA.Rows
    dict.Add Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(rw.Value)), Chr(0)), rw.Row
Next rw

For Each rw In rngB.Rows
    tmp = Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(rw.Value)), Chr(0))
    If dict.exists(tmp) Then
    Else
        rw.Cells(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next rw

End Sub
```

I attempt to compare a 20k rows record column against another 20k rows column in another worksheet. Error '13' was trigger in this line of code:

```
dict.Add Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(rw.Value)), Chr(0)), rw.Row
```

I am new to excel VBA programming, sorry if I could'nt explain it clearly. Please let me know if there is any mistakes in my code.

Comment: Transpose will fail if there are more rows than excel has possible columns... that's all ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel, are you sure? This seem to work [fastest-way-to-find-a-row-in-excel-range-using-excel-macro-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685622/fastest-way-to-find-a-row-in-excel-range-using-excel-macro-vba/22704708#answer-22704708). @Dvid Maybe more than 255 chars in a cell [vba-scripting-dictionary-run-time-error-13-type-mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549379/vba-scripting-dictionary-run-time-error-13-type-mismatch#answer-17817522)? If not show the value of `rw.value` at error.

Comment: @BitAccesser haven't seen the `For Each rw In rng.Rows` part... this way the 2^16 limit will never be hit... but having just one column, `rw` will only be one cell which cannot be transposed at all as `rw.Value` isn't an array. pretty obvious if reading the whole code... (I should do this more often) :P

Comment: the two `with ...` blocks add extra lines that do not need to be there  ... just use this for the first one ... similar to the other one   .....  `Row1Last = sht1.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: the variable name `Row1Last` implies that it means the last (maybe last used) cell in a particular row....  variable name `colGLast` or `colG_last`, meaning last cell in column G, is more descriptive....  or 'lastBOSrow'   meaning last row on BOS sheet

Comment: @BitAccesser Thank you for your reply. The value where it hits the error is "1020001TL200000", is there any problem with the value? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for the function got lost, while copied several times.
This is the original I think [fastest-way-to-find-a-row-in-excel-range-using-excel-macro-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685622/fastest-way-to-find-a-row-in-excel-range-using-excel-macro-vba/22704708#answer-22704708).

Have a look at the comments

```vb
For Each rw In rngA.Rows
    'Create a key from the entire row and map to row
    ' If your rows are not unique you'll have to do a bit more work here
    ' and use an array for the key value(s)
    dict.Add Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(rw.Value)), Chr(0)), rw.Row
Next rw
```

You need unique rows in `rngA` or you get an array, that causes error 13.
See [Using-the-Dictionary-Class-in-VBA](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/3391/Using-the-Dictionary-Class-in-VBA.html)

That kind of problems can be avoided, using a database instead of an Excel-File.